# RadioButtons Xaml vs C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new in XAML/WPF and there is something I dont understand.

I don't understand why my 3 radioButtons are bound together when I add them directly in the XAML code, and why they aren't when I add them with C#.

What I mean by "Bound" is that they dont uncheck their selves when I check another one...

```
<Border Background="#3B3B3B" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="75"/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" 
                        Grid.Column="0" 
                        Name="CatMenu"
                        CanVerticallyScroll="True">
                <RadioButton/>
                <RadioButton/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
</Border>
```

```
foreach (string folder in folders)
            {
                Border border = new Border();
                RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton
                {
                    Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folder),
                    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
                    Foreground = Brushes.White,
                    Height = 70,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
                };

                border.Child = radioButton;
                CatMenu.Children.Add(border);
            }
```

Comment: You have accepted the wrong answer. See [answer of @Ash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75568115/3141792) to learn the correct explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In XAML, if you put multiple radio buttons inside a container like a StackPanel, the system automatically groups them together. This means that only one radio button in the group can be selected at a time, and selecting one will unselect the others in the same group.

When you create radio buttons in C# code, you have to manually set the group name if you want them to behave like the ones in XAML. By default, each radio button you create in C# is in its own group, so selecting one won't affect the others.

To group radio buttons together in C#, you just need to set the GroupName property to the same value for all of them. For example, you could set it to "MyGroup" for all the radio buttons you want to group together.

That way, when you select one radio button, it will unselect any others in the same group that were previously selected.

Comment: *"When you create radio buttons in C# code, you have to manually set the group name if you want them to behave like the ones in XAML"* - This is not correct. The reason for the behavior is that the RadioButton elements don't share a common parent. Instead, in the provided C# version each RadioButton has its own parent (a Border element). This answer shouldn't be the accepted answer as the explanation is wrong. Given the context of individual parent elements, your proposed solution is correct (if the buttons are intentionally wrapped into a dedicated Border opposed to the XAML version).

Answer (score 2):

your c# code is not equivalent to xaml markup. in xaml you added RadioButtons directly to StackPanel. in code you put each RadioButton in a different Border element. they have a different parent and are not bound together.

```
foreach (string folder in folders)
{
    RadioButton radioButton = new RadioButton
    {
        Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(folder),
        Background = Brushes.Transparent,
        Foreground = Brushes.White,
        Height = 70,
        VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center
    };

    CatMenu.Children.Add(radioButton);
}
```

if you are going to use Borders, you will have to assign the same GroupName to all button, as [mentioned in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.radiobutton?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#remarks)